# How clion redirects output by setting the configuration

Tags: redirect, clion

I want to use clion to redirect the output to a specified file, but I don't want to configure it in the code, for example, by setting it via freopen.
Previously I was redirecting via freopen, but this way every time I submit the code on oj, I need to comment the freopen code, which is very inconvenient

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTmK5.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8POR.png)
I can't find the relevant configuration in clion's configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but currenly CLion has no this functionality.
`>MyOutput.txt` in `Program arguments` does nothing because `CLion` don't run it through a shell, which normally would be responsible for setting up the redirection from the command line.

Please, vote
[CPP-3379 Add an option to redirect program output and error streams to a file](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-3379)